# Client transferring file from web server to another machine

Tags: tomcat, servlets

There is a Tomcat web server, say WS1, on which I have all my servlets and HTML pages. A client of WS1 uploads a file on WS1. That file is then read, encrypted and stored on WS1 in some other folder.

What I have to do is send/transfer this encrypted file on some other machine, say machine A. Suppose client searches for the file he has stored, that file should be downloaded to WS1 from the machine A. WS1 will perform decryption and that decrypted file should be sent on the client.

I have completed upto the encryption part but got stuck with the file transfer. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here a. "file should be downloaded to WS1 from the machine A" or it should be b."file should be downloaded to machine A from the web server".

This actually contradicts your question title and body of question.

If "b." is what you want (probably it should be),t

Then, You need to write code to download file from web server WS1.

Here is the excerpt to download file using Servlet.

```
String value = "attachment;filename=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8") +'"';
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", value);

OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(my_file);
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int length;
while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
     // logic to decrypt the file
    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
in.close();
out.flush();
```

You'll need to handle the appropriate exceptions, of course.

Comment: Thanx.. Ur code will be helpful for me in the later part for downloading.

Comment: Can u please specify i above code what should be replaced with filename and my_file. I had tried replacing my_file with "http://169.254.174.150:8084/WebApplication1/files/encrypt.txt" and filename by encrypt.txt but it isn't working. Also i am not getting where the file will be stored.. Please help.  
thanx..

Comment: If your files at mentioned example location. Then just `request.getContextPath()/files/encrypt.txt` will work in Servlet